# How to clear filters on cell within range, but not within a table

Tags: excel, reactjs, typescript, office-js, office-addins

I'm working with some large excel files, mostly removing rows and applying formatting if they fit some criteria. One of the rows to remove contains a filter, so when trying to delete Excel throws a `GeneralException`. I'm aware of the `clearFilters()` method of `Excel.Table` ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.table?view=office-js#clearfilters--)). However, attempting to `sheet.tables` (after loading and syncing) reveals that there are none. I've been working with ranges because of this, but I can't find another method to remove filters from a cell/range other than the Table one.

Is there a way to clear filters using ranges? If it helps, the filter is always on cell A1.

EDIT: I didn't specify earlier, but I'm writing this in React/Typescript, not VBA.

Comment: In general, I would say that any API that throws "GeneralException" might have an overarching issue.  So feel free to file a bug at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues, where someone from the product team should be able to take note of it.

Answer (score 2):

I would think that you would want to clear all the filters on the sheet.  If so, this works for the entire sheet:

```
If Sheets("YourSheetName").FilterMode = True Then
    Sheets("YourSheetName").ShowAllData
End If
```

This first checks if any filters are set, because otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rey. I didn't specify what I'm using to write the add in though, so it's my fault, but I'm not using VBA. I'm writing it with React/Typescript, so these methods aren't available